# How to set custom display resolution normally

Tags: ati, display, resolution, monitor, tv

I need help with setting a custom display resolution on Linux Ubuntu,
because I have a shitty TV which is actually 1080p, but 1080p looks like crap on it. However, 1776x1000 looks perfect, but Ubuntu doesn't have a resolution of 1776x1000, only a lower one.

I tried adding the resolution with terminal: xrandr.
It added the resolution, but the problem is when I switch to 1776x1000, it still looks like it is in 1920x1080, only zoomed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution is not only a factor of your TV (whose details you didn't specify) but also of your graphics card *and your module* (aka "driver").  So if your TV supports a 1776x1000, but your graphics card (which you didn't specify neither) doesn't, it'll just "scale" to the nearest solution which seems to be 1920*1080.

Otherwise, you'll have to go down to 1280*720, which is a well-known resolution...  :-(

Look up the exact model number of both your TV and graphics card and if both *do* support 1776*1000 and it still looks <strike>like crap</strike> bad, you'll have to raise a bug report for your "driver" and wait patiently until the developers do something about it.

Also: some TVs automatically "zoom" (aka "overscan") the images they receive.  You might *test* by turning this feature off by using the TV settings menu with your remote control (look this up in the manual of your TV)

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as both of our reputations will go up!  ;-)